# Need some software/tool to estimate my project based on hours and not story points

Tags: web-apps

I'm looking for a tool that works somewhat like this:

- I give a project a set of tasks.
- I estimate the tasks based on hours.
- I set the order of which tasks come first.
- I set how many hours each day is and how many days I have in a week for the project.
- I get something visual like a calendar that shows me dates and tasks in a timeline.
- I can tell my salesforce when I can get X and Y done by dates and hours.

Thanks :)

EDIT:

Web application would be preferred. We don't use Windows, so if desktop something for Linux or OS X (Mac).

Comment: Online or standalone? And if standalone, what OS? Estimated project sizes? Only task order, or also task dependencies? Only the estimates or do you also want to keep track of the task realization? Please [edit](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/posts/13474/edit)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend for you to use Microsoft team foundation server this includes reporting, requirements management, project management (for both agile software development and waterfall teams), automated builds and code-depository  testing and release management capabilities. basically it covers the entire Application Life-cycle Management,hope my answer will help you,let us know if your expecting something different than this

[image: Source Image from dotnetcurry.com]